# How to get row limiting by value from two columns

Tags: sql-server

Please advice how to combine query, to find first occurrence of row

I have table

```
Date        Counter
01.01.2005  208,5
02.01.2005  209,5 <----- start
03.01.2005  210,5
04.01.2005  211,5
08.01.2005  16,5
09.01.2005  17,2
10.01.2005  18,8  <------ correct
11.01.2005  19,7
12.01.2005  20,7
13.01.2005  21
14.01.2005  116,3
15.01.2005  120,4
16.01.2005  135,2
17.01.2005  1,1
18.01.2005  10,3
19.01.2005  18,7 <------ wrong
20.01.2005  14,2
21.01.2005  8,5
22.01.2005  7,1
```

and I need to extract Date by Counter 18.5 (from starting date 02.01.2005), since this value not in the table possible to take next higher value.

I tried to search by using starting date (because table have thousand dates and Counter between 0-499) and limit for value (grater or equal).

```
select top 1 Date from Tabel1 where  Date > 02.01.2005 AND Counter >= 18.5
```

this query return wrong result - date 03.01.2005,
but correct must be 10.01.2005.
Hope for any assistance. Thanks in advance.

(I use: sql 2008 r).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an `ORDER BY` clause when using `TOP`. In this case you want to get the lowest `Counter`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM tbl
WHERE 
    Date > CAST('20050102' AS DATE)
    AND Counter >= 18.5
ORDER BY Counter
```

Note that without the `ORDER BY`, the result of `TOP 1` is not guaranteed to always be the same.

Comment: thanks for your answer . 
But this also return wrong result (date some where at the far, but must be near). May be due to that table have more than one values (about 18.5).  For example (continuing to my list by date): Counter = 21 _116 _120 _135 _ 1 _10 _18 _14 _8 _7 _3 _0 _495.
So, I mean, is it possible to find first  occurrence of this value which is near to 18.5, from this (02.01.2005) starting date?